# Jquery autocomplete (not UI) issue with drop down in IE7

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I'm using Jquery autocomplete v1.1 (not jquery UI).

Drop down of autocomplete has an issue in IE7. It doesnt come up properly if there is a single record in the result.

also click on any other area doest disappear the drop down.

every thing work fine in IE 6.

kindly suggest.